# Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. lstset

Tags: listings

I am facing an issue for, nothing yet worked. Yes, the code is okay, it should be good. I reinstalled the complete MiKTeX environment, yet the problem appears.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont,
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
  belowcaptionskip={6pt},
  columns=fixed,
  extendedchars=true,
  frame=single,
  escapechar=\%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
var decompressedMochiKit = function(p,a,c
    ,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":
    e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.
    fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))}
    ...
}(...);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Why is the closing `}` inside the `lstlisting` environment causing a problem?

Answer (score 1):

With the `escapechar=\%` setting, the `%` in the third line of the listing tells LaTeX to start interpreting the tokens up to a matching `%` as LaTeX code. But there is *no* matching `%`, so when LaTeX finds an unbalanced `}` it complains.

Remove `escapechar=\%`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `escapechar=\%` setting in the lstset.

Comment: You'll need to explain a little more here. What if you wanted to use `%` as an escape character?